How can I display unique data associated with param on individual pages in SvelteKit using slug/parameter routing
I'm currently working on a SvelteKit project where I have a list of cards representing different law firms. Each card is linked to a unique page using slug/parameter routing. I've managed to fetch the titles of the law firms dynamically, ensuring they are unique. However, I'm struggling with displaying specific data associated with each law firm on its respective page, particularly a table allocated to that law firm.
Here's what I've tried so far:
Successfully implemented slug/parameter routing to dynamically generate unique pages for each law firm.
Fetched and displayed the titles of the law firms on their respective pages.
However, I'm unsure about how to proceed with displaying specific data, like a table, allocated to each law firm based on the slug/parameter.
I'm using Supabase as the backend.
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
This is the card page
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import { paginate, LightPaginationNav } from 'svelte-paginate';
    export let data;

    let search = '';
    let visibleLawFirms = [];
    let currentPage = 1;
    let pageSize = 12;

    // Recalculate paginatedItems whenever visibleLawFirms changes
    $: paginatedItems = paginate({ items: visibleLawFirms, pageSize, currentPage });

    // component mounts to dom before search is performed
    onMount(() => {
        updateVisibleLawFirms();
    });

    function updateVisibleLawFirms() {
        if (search) {
            visibleLawFirms = data.lawfirm.filter((lawF) => {
                return lawF.lawfirmname.toLowerCase().includes(search);
            });
        } else {
            visibleLawFirms = data.lawfirm;
        }
    }

    function updateSearch(e) {
        search = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
        updateVisibleLawFirms();
    }

    function handlePageChange(e) {
        currentPage = e.detail.page;
    }
</script>

<div class="flexLawSearch">
    <h1 class="leftAlign">Law Firms</h1>
    <div class="searchAndAdd">
        <input
            class="searchBox"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search Law Firms..."
            bind:value={search}
            on:input={updateSearch}
        />
        <a href="addfirm"><button class="defaultBlue">+ New Firm</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<ul class="flexCards">
    {#each paginatedItems as LawF}
        <a href="/lawfirms/{encodeURIComponent(LawF.lawfirmname)}">
            <li class="cardShape">
                <h3>{LawF.lawfirmname}</h3>
            </li>
        </a>
    {/each}
</ul>

This is the page where I'm struggling with fetching the unique data
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';
    export let data;
    console.log(data);

    const lawfirmId = $page.params.lawfirmId;
</script>

<div class="lawFirmBanner">
    <h1>{decodeURIComponent(lawfirmId)}</h1>
</div>

{#if data.lawfirm}
    <div class="lawFirmInfo">
        <p>{data.lawfirm[3].lawfirmname}</p>  <!-- Figure out how to match the param for unique data for each firm-->
    
    </div>
{/if}


You generally should not need to access parameters on a page like that. The load function should read the parameter and return all data relevant to the given entry.

Do you have an api endpoint where you can get the data for the individual law firm? Or how are you trying to get the data for the individual law firm?
